# How to disconect listen port ( http ) in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

For example, it is a tunnel, and I want to shut down for 10 minutes and then after the timeout would listen in on again. 
This socket has my packet to the node-webkit. 
I've tried several times but still failed and error.

```
var server = http.createServer( r, q ){
  //some code
}).listen(8080);
server.on( 'error', function(){ /* handle */ });
server.on( 'close', function(){ /* handle */ });
```

How do I totally stop the listener port without having to shut down the node-webkit ?

Comment: Presumably the listener is disconnected before the "error" or "close" events are fired, right?

Comment: That example alone, I already fixed

Answer (score 0):

According to the API docs, the listener is closed when the [`close` event is emitted](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_event_close), so there is no need to close it manually.  Presumably the listener is also closed when the `error` event is emitted; however, I don't see that event documented anywhere.

See also the [`server.close(...)` (with optional callback)](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_server_close_callback) method for reference.

Comment: Congratulations on 24 000 000 post! ;)